# DB210.1 FP5 LOAD command error

Tags: db2, load

I have one DB2 10.1 database table (this database us upgraded from 9.7). I am trying to load an ixf/del file from another server, which has DB2 9.7 FP10. Getting below error. Also tried from Win 7 machine which had DB2 9 client but same error. Both databases are running on windows server 2012 R2.

> SQL3015N  An SQL error "-572" occurred during processing.

Commands used:

1) `db2 load from C:\work.txt of del replace into SCHEMA.work nonrecoverable`

2) `db2 load from C:\work.ixf of ixf replace into SCHEMA.work nonrecoverable`

For this error I found http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00572n.html article on the IBM site but what exactly they say I don't understand.

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: IFX and delimited are two different formats; what format is your file exactly?  Anyway, it sounds like you are trying to run your commands on down-level clients agains a 10.1 server. The `LOAD` command, at least in the form you are using, must be run on the server.

Comment: @mustaccio The `LOAD` command in this form can be executed from a client, but the file being loaded must exist on the server.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde yes files being loaded is on db server, command is from down level db2.  mustaccio- I tried with both format but both failed. I expected ixf format to work as its common for all db2 version.